# iPhone Deck Game Loop

Tags: iphone, game-loop

can anyone tell the best approach to run game loop like Uno or Herats (Deck Game)

```
[CPU2 turn];
[CPU3 turn];
[User turn]; // Wait to get user input before proceed to [CPU4 turn]
[CPU4 turn];
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could make turns into `NSOperation` subclass instances placed into an `NSOperationQueue`, which is set to allow only one concurrent turn/operation. In this case, turns are handled in first-in-first-out (FIFO) order. You can read more about this in Apple's [Managing Concurrency](http://developer.apple.com/cocoa/managingconcurrency.html) document.